# How to call a function in an ASP.NET code-behind file from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Actually I am looking to show an image in my div by calling a function of code behind file. Since my image tag is dynamically binding from JavaScript, how can I call a function with parameter. Below is the code which I used to call, but its not working, even its not hitting the function in debug mode.

```
document.getElementById("divthumbnail").innerHTML = '<img src="'<%=test()%>'"/>';
```

So, how can I modify this code, to get an image URL?

Comment: As server side code is not direct available client side, you'll need AJAX to do that.

Comment: The suggested duplicate will suggest web methods etc. However, if this is ASP.NET WebForms why don't you make the image control `runat=server` and set the URL in the page load event? Alternatively you could add a Literal control and write some JS into it from page load - just a `var` containing the url string, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a ScriptManager component as required in you markup like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" 
    EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

and having this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        PageMethods.YourMethod();
    }
</script>
```

Then you can define a WebMethod in your code behind like this:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string YourMethod()
{

}
```